# setListAdapter multiple items?

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible to have `SimpleCursorAdapter` retrieve multiple items and have them display? This is from the android Notepad tutorial(edited a bit) and when I try to have it pull `AScoresDbAdapter.KEY_COL2_NAME, AScoresDbAdapter.KEY_COL1_DATE` it only displays the first one in the `TextView`

Is there a reason for this or am I missing something?

```
private void fillData() {
    // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
    Cursor c = scoresDbAdapter.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] from = new String[] { AScoresDbAdapter.KEY_COL2_NAME, AScoresDbAdapter.KEY_COL1_DATE};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };

    // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.shots_row, c, from, to,0);
    setListAdapter(notes);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I guess it slipped pass me at first that they are arrays and that it is probably putting one `from` with one `int` so I added another `TextView` and edited the above to this:

```
String[] from = new String[] { AScoresDbAdapter.KEY_COL1_DATE,AScoresDbAdapter.KEY_COL2_NAME};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2 };
```

And now it displays `[Date][Name]` instead of just `[Date]` or `[Name]`

Not sure if this this the correct way, but if there is a better one I would be glad to know of it.